# Why preg_match_all forces me to provide the 3rd optional parameter?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm counting the **number of some special characters** (like euro symbol) in `$text`, using `preg_match_all` and this regular expression:

```
preg_match_all('/[\[|\]|€\{|}|\\|\^|\||~]/u', $text);
```

For some strange reason PHP asks me for a **third parameter**. But it's supposed to be optional as per [documentation of preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

> Warning: preg_match_all() expects at least 3 parameters, 2 given.

If i provide `PREG_PATTERN_ORDER` (even don't know why should i) i get:

> Cannot pass parameter 3 by reference.

So, what's wrong with my code? Here is the whole function if needed:

```
public function getMessageCount($text)
{
    $specials   = preg_match_all('/[\[|\]|€\{|}|\\|\^|\||~]/u', $text)
    $characters = strlen($text) + $specials;

    if(in_array(strtolower($this->method), self::$classic_plans)) :

        if($characters >= 0   && $characters <= 160) return 1;
        if($characters >= 161 && $characters <= 306) return 2;
        if($characters >= 307 && $characters <= 459) return 3;
        if($characters >= 460 && $characters <= 612) return 4;

        return 5;

    endif;

    if(in_array(strtolower($this->method), self::$basic_plans)) :

        if($characters >= 0    && $characters <= 160)  return 1;
        if($characters >= 161  && $characters <= 312)  return 2;
        if($characters >= 313  && $characters <= 468)  return 3;
        if($characters >= 469  && $characters <= 624)  return 4;
        if($characters >= 625  && $characters <= 780)  return 5;
        if($characters >= 781  && $characters <= 936)  return 6;
        if($characters >= 937  && $characters <= 1092) return 7;
        if($characters >= 1093 && $characters <= 1248) return 8;

        return 9;

    endif;

    return in_array(strtolower($this->method), self::$zero_plans) ? 1 : null;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although 3rd parameter became optional in 5.4.0 like others have said already but your code doesn't compile even if you pass 3rd parameter because you said you pass PREG_PATTERN_ORDER flag but 3rd parameter is supposed to be the array that receives matches and 4th parameter is flag.

Use something like the [following](http://ideone.com/fixoL):

```
<?php
$dummy = array();
echo("Result = ".preg_match_all('/[\[|\]|x\{|}|\\|\^|\||~]/', $text, $dummy));
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

It became optional from PHP 5.4.0.

> **Changelog**
>
> 5.4.0      The matches parameter became optional.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the changelog in the link you provided. After that, check your PHP version ;)

Comment: i.e. `5.4.0  The matches parameter became optional.`

Answer (score 1):

the return value `preg_match_all` is an int → number of matches. The matches text will be filled in the 3<sup>rd</sup> parameter.

```
// incorrect
$specials = preg_match_all('/[\[|\]|€\{|}|\\|\^|\||~]/u', $text);      

// correct
$num = preg_match_all('/[\[|\]|€\{|}|\\|\^|\||~]/u', $text, $specials);
```